# Hypothesis of Riesz's representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

The Riesz representation states that

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space. Then for any linear and continuous functional $x^{\ast}:H \to \mathbb{K}$ there is a unique element $y \in H$ such that $x^\ast(x) = \langle x, y\rangle\ \forall x \in X$, and conversely, if $y \in H$, then $x^\ast:H \to K, x^\ast(x) = \langle x, y \rangle\ \forall x \in H$, is linear and continuous, with $\|x^\ast\|=\|y\|$.

Now the question is, can we replace "Hilbert space" with "prehilbertian space"?

Well, for the moment I don't think so. My thoughts so far are that I have to find a non complete space $X$, such as $C[a, b]$ with the inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f(t)g(t)dt$, and in that space, find a functional for which there exists $x \in X$ such that $x^\ast(x) \neq \langle x, y\rangle\ \forall y \in X$.

Something else that I could do, is find a functional for which there exists $y, y' \in X$, $y \neq y'$ such that $\forall x \in X$, $x^\ast(x) = \langle x, y\rangle = \langle x, y' \rangle$.

For the moment, I didn't manage to find a counter example, so if you could give me directions for where to look, that would be great.

Tanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Take a Hilbert space made from a pre-Hilbert space (such as $L^2[a,b]$ from $C[a,b]$). Since $C[a,b]$ embeds in $L^2[a,b]$, take any functional on $L^2[a,b]$ coming from a non-continuous function. It will be a linear functional on $C[a,b]$, but will not be given by inner product with any element of $C[a,b]$.

Comment: Wow thank you @Neal, that was easy in fact. I feel dumb now ahahaha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a Hilbert space made from a pre-Hilbert space (such as $L^2[a,b]$ from $C[a,b]$). Since $C[a,b]$ embeds in $L^2[a,b]$, take any functional on $L^2[a,b]$ coming from a function that does not have a continuous representative. It will be a linear functional on $C[a,b]$, but will not be given by inner product with any element of $C[a,b]$. -- [Neal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001147/hypothesis-of-rieszs-representation-theorem#comment2046432_1001147)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not think about taking a Hilbert space made from a prehilbertian space. 
Considering your answer, I think we still need to be careful about "taking any functional coming from a non-continuous function". For example, I took the functional given by $Tf= \int_a^b f(t)\phi(t)dt$ where $\phi$ is non-continuous. If $\phi(x) = x, a < x \leq b$ and $\phi(x) = x+1, x=a$, then $\phi$ is non-continuous but $Tf=\langle f, g \rangle$ where $g(x) = x\ \forall x \in [a,b]$.